# Is untapping my permanents during the untap step optional?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was reading the untap step rule and got confused a bit. It says:

> 502.2. Second, the active player determines which permanents he or she controls will untap. Then he or she untaps them all simultaneously.
>   This turn-based action doesn't use the stack. Normally, all of a
>   player's permanents untap, but effects can keep one or more of a
>   player's permanents from untapping.

If "a player determines", can I determine not to untap all my permanents?

Comment: **Very** good question - the idea is actually not uncommon.

Comment: See [Giant Oyster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=108816) for an example of this rule being overridden by a card.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You do not get to choose whether or not to keep a permanent tapped during the Untap Step of the Beginning Phase unless [a specific card's ability](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[choose]+[not]+[to]+[untap]) provides that choice. For example, [Rubinia Soulsinger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430410) lets you choose not to untap her during your untap step. Notice that the clause "your untap step." is important, [Rubinia Soulsinger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430410) must still be untapped if an opponent plays a [Pestermite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=pestermite) you must untap [Rubinia Soulsinger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430410) and relinquish control of whatever creature you stole.

The word "determine" in this context does not mean choose, it means to evaluate whether or not there are any abilities preventing a permanent from untapping, and evaluating the decision to untap *should an ability provide that choice*. As the rule states:

> Normally, all of a player's permanents untap.

Answer (score 12):

Actually the answer is in the text you posted:

> Normally, all of a player's permanents untap, but effects can keep one or more of a player's permanents from untapping.

So, no, a player cannot chose which permanents to untap during that step, unless an effect  makes it so.